# New to OOP and Objective-C, confused on how to instantiate one class inside a another

Tags: objective-c, oop, libpcap, geoip

I've been writing C code for quite some time but am very new to Objective-C and OO program design. I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to design my program and it's classes -- my standby procedural programming paradigm of passing an opaque pointer to everything just won't die a quiet death. I am writing a simple program in Xcode4 in Objective-C and I have some questions on design and convention. I've designed two classes "PacketCapture" and "IPGeo". The first is a light wrapper around libpcap with some added parsing logic and the second is a light wrapper around MaxMind's GeoIP C API. In my main module, I instantiate the PacketCapture class and pass control to the packet capture loop:

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        PacketCapture *_PacketCapture = [[PacketCapture alloc] init:"en1" withFilter:""];
        if (_PacketCapture == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can't instantiate PacketCapture class");
            return (-1);
        }
        IPGeo *_IPGeo = [[IPGeo alloc] init:"/usr/local/share/GeoIP/GeoIPCity.dat"];
        if (_IPGeo == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Can't instantiate IPGeo class");
            return (-1);
        }

        NSLog(@"entering packet loop...");
        [_PacketCapture packetCapture];
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Inside of the `packetCapture` method a parsing function is called that chops up the packet and displays it. I need to use the GeoIP logic down inside the parsing code to lookup the IP addresses against the geo database. Therein lies my problem and general confusion.

My questions:

- Where should I instantiate the GeoIP class?
- Is having an infinite loop inside an object in a class bad OO design? Feels like it could be. Perhaps if I restructure this problem will be easily solved?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that your identifiers `_PacketCapture` and `_IPGeo` are classified as reserved by the C standard. It's unlikely to cause any issues but just keep in mind that all identifiers beginning with an underscore and an uppercase letter (or identifiers beginning with two consecutive underscores) are reserved, and using reserved identifiers is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where should I instantiate the GeoIP class?

If `PacketCapture` requires an `IPGeo` object to function, I would recommend instantiating it within `PacketCapture`'s `-init` method. If you need to configure the `IPGeo` object (by passing a different path when initialized, for example) before using it in `PacketCapture`, and the path to use is determined in a way `PacketCapture` shouldn't be aware of, have the class responsible for managing the two (or, in your case, the main loop of the program) create an instance and pass it as an argument to a custom initializer method on the `PacketCapture` class.

A bit of nitpicking--your initializer for `IPGeo` doesn't follow Objective-C conventions for expressive method names. `-initWithPathToDatabase:` would look a lot better in my opinion.

In a similar vein, you can add a `-initWithIPGeo:` method to your `PacketCapture` class.

> Is having an infinite loop inside an object in a class bad OO design?

If this is an iOS or Cocoa application, then definitely yes. If it's a command line tool, then maybe. Furthermore, if that infinite loop is being run on the main thread, it will block all UI elements, which will make your program look unresponsive.

A better alternative would be to use the protocol/delegate pattern, a staple of Objective-C programs. Create a protocol with something like the following method:

```
- (void)packetCapture:(PacketCapture *)packetCapture didReceiveDataFromIPAddress:(NSString *)ipAddress;
```

Then create a delegate object that implements this protocol and performs an action on receiving the packets. If you're making a command line tool, you can instantiate that delegate and wait to receive messages.

Comment: This is my first Objective-C program, and yes it's a simple command line tool -- meant to be more illustrative than useful. This is all great advice, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few concerns with this code:

1. You are using *reserved identifiers* (any identifier beginning with two underscores or an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved). As I mentioned in the comment, it's unlikely to cause any real issues but it is something to consider.
2. A more “Cocoa” approach for initialiser methods is to accept either a filename or an `NSData` object containing the contents of the file. The latter has the benefit that the data does not necessarily have to be sourced from a file on a disk. For example:

   ```
   NSData *geoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file"];
   IPGeo *ipGeo = [[IPGeo alloc] initWithData:geoData];
   ```

   In the `initWithData:` method, you would either parse the data as raw bytes, or perhaps convert it to a string and parse that, etc. In any case, `init:` is not a very good name for a method because it is not clear what the method expects. If you still want it to accept a filename, a good name may be `initWithContentsOfFile:` (and have it accept an `NSString` rather than just a `const char *`).

   Likewise, with your `PacketCapture` initialiser method. Objective-C gives you the benefit of being able to name your arguments and this allows for semi-self-documenting code, so method naming is incredibly important in Objective-C, if only to remain consistent with all other commonly used frameworks.
3. There is nothing wrong with implementing an infinite loop in a method, this is more-or-less what `NSApplication` does with its `run` method. There *are* alternatives to this, such as threading, or using run loops, etc, but for small command-line utilities there is seldom any benefit. I would suggest expanding and renaming your method just a little bit:

   ```
   // Methods are usually named as if you are telling the object what to do
   [packetCapture capturePackets];

   // or, if you think this might be of some benefit:
   NSDate *stopTime = /* specify a time to stop */;
   [packetCapture capturePacketsUntilDate:stopTime];

   // This could also allows for indefinite running with:
   [packetCapture capturePacketsUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
   ```
4. If `PacketCapture` requires an instance of `IPGeo` to function, then `PacketCapture` should accept `IPGeo` as part of its initialiser (again, I renamed the method to what I think it should be):

   ```
   PacketCapture *packetCapture = [[PacketCapture alloc] initWithIPGeo:ipGeo interface:@"en1"];
   ```

   Alternatively, the `PacketCapture` class could allocate and initialise the `IPGeo` class itself, but this creates a tight couple between the two classes.

Comment: +1 for bringing up reserved identifiers, identifying classes with loops like `NSApplication`.

Answer (score 0):

By "`GeoIP` class", do you mean `IPGeo`?  Where you instantiate it depends on several factors.  If you only need it inside one parsing method in the `IPGeo` class, instantiate it there.  If you need it throughout the lifetime of an `IPGeo` object, instantiate it in the designated initialiser instead and keep it in an instance variable.

An infinite loop is not intrinsically a bad thing, but there are usually better approaches.  What platform are you developing for?

By the way, `NSString` literals have a `@` prefix, such as: `@"foo"`.  You are using plain C strings, which will probably cause a crash if you pass them into any Objective-C code that is expecting an `NSString`.